# How can i specify attribute of my own ViewGroup(Layout) in an axml file?

Tags: android-layout, xamarin.android, android-xml, xamarin

I'm trying to adapt [Ravi Tamada](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/12/android-dashboard-design-tutorial/)'s blog entry to Mono for Android.

But at the 6. step i stopped. How can i specify

```
<!-- Your package folder -->
<com.androidhive.dashboard.DashboardLayout ...
```

attribute, at fragment_layout.xml file?

I try to give a package name specified at [Xamarin](http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/532644-monodroid-how-to-use-custom-attributes-inside-a-layout-axml-file-) solution or specify my VS2010 namespace at java form (MySolution.MyProject.MyFolder.DashboardLayout -> mysolution.myproject.myfolder.DashboardLayout) but result is same error:

Design mode gives following: "the layout could not be loaded: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.mockview cannot be cast to android.view.viewgroup"

The question is, how can i use my DashboardLayout.cs (ViewGroup) class as attribute like Ravi Tamada's java example. (6. step)

Thaanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a bug in Mono for Android/the Designer and is already filed on Bugzilla here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7680

Hopefully this will be fixed soon, you can CC yourself on the bug so you can updates when anything changes.